# Android Studio never deploys app

Tags: android, debugging, deployment, genymotion

The strangest thing happened overnight. I try to debug an app from Android Studio to Genymotion. I see Gradle build finishing, but the app is never deployed. Thereafter the debug button gets disabled. The same story occurs with the run button. And neither SHIFT+F9 nor SHIFT+F10 work. Has anyone faced this problem as well?

I am using Android Studio 1.5 RC1 and latest Genymotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above solution doesn't work, just try re-installing Android Studio. And when installing, make sure HAXM is installed properly. Use this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) for reference. I used to have the same issue too.

Comment: Thanks that was a great tip. What happened now I can recall was an update on the Canary version of Android Studio. I only had to reinstall it leaving Android SDK alone and Genymotion. And this time the app finished building and got deployed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run > Edit Configurations... and setting like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks QuangTV for your answer, I have the same settings. I have tried also creating a brand new application and seems strange I can see the genymotion virtual devices, but as I mentioned the app is built but it silently doesn't deploy or installs in the virtual device.